# Beginner issue: Errors loading .el files in Emacs

Tags: emacs, gdb

I'm an Emacs beginner. I just installed a Emacs on Linux. I want to integrate Emacs with `gdb`.

Based on some instruction from the internet, I downloaded 2 `.el` files: `multi-gdb-ui.el` and `multi-gud.el`. I put these 2 files in

```
/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gdb-ui.el
```

and

```
/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gud.el
```

I created a new `.emacs` file. I only put the following lines in it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat .emacs
(setq gdb-many-windows t)
;; this is used for GDB
(load-library "/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gud.el")
(load-library "/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gdb-ui.el")
```

Then I launched Emacs. But I got many errors. It asked me to launch it with `--debug-init`,
so I ran the following:

```
emacs --debug-init
```

I got these errors:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable overlay-arrow-variable-list)

add-to-list(overlay-arrow-variable-list gud-overlay-arrow-position)

eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gud.el" nil t)

load-with-code-conversion("/tmp/test/emacs/multi-gud.el" "/tmp/shili/emacs/multi-gud.el" nil nil)

load("/tmp/shili/emacs/multi-gud.el")

load-library("/tmp/shili/emacs/multi-gud.el")

eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "~/.emacs" nil t)

load-with-code-conversion("/root/.emacs" "~/.emacs" t t)

load("~/.emacs" t t)  

#[nil "^H\205\227^@   ▒=\203^Q^@▒^H▒Q\2025^@  ▒=\203'^@▒▒▒▒#\203#^@▒\2025^@▒\2025^@   ▒=\2031^@▒\2025^@▒^H▒Q^Z▒^S▒\n▒\211#\210^K▒=\203F^@▒^S^K\203\210^@▒^K!▒\232\203$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

So how can I load these 2 `.el` files successfully?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C and C++?

Comment: You would need to add your temp directory(ies) to the load path -- `/tmp/shili/emacs/` and `/tmp/test/emacs/` or put the files in a directory that is already wired for that -- e.g., `~/.emacs.d` -- See:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html

Comment: Great thank you, Lawlist. Your answer is fully correct.

Comment: I'm very beginner for stackoverflow. Not sure how to set your information as the correct answer.

Comment: @user3226901 -- thank you for letting us know that your issue has been resolved.  I've turned the comment into an answer for you to check off as being resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be caused because the folders containing the source files at issue have apparently not been added to the load-path of Emacs.  In this particular case, the original poster may either add the following directories to the load-path (i.e., `/tmp/shili/emacs/` and `/tmp/test/emacs/`); or, the source files at issue may be placed inside an Emacs directory that is already wired with the load-path.

The following links contain relevant documentation relating to the load-path, which may be helpful in that regard:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html

Comment: Hmm. You make it sound as if `~/.emacs.d` is in the load-path by default, but it isn't (and indeed shouldn't be).

Comment: @phils -- thank you -- I've removed the example of `~/.emacs.d`.